# Android webview, how to set back press work only in the page where webview first loads

Tags: android, webview

i am building a webapp, i am using webview to load webpages. everything works fine till here.

i gave a particular url say "www.google.co.in" in webview to load it. it loads fine, when user clicks links in the particular view it goes to the corresponding page, ok..

now here is what i want i want on backbutton to work only when the webview "www.google.com" is loaed. for all the other web pages the on backpress should return "sorry you cant go back"

say something like this

```
  if(webview=="www.google.co.in")
  {
    myfunc()
     {

     }
   }
   else
  {
     myanotherfunc()
      {

      }
  }
```

Comment: you can get loaded url like this: `String webUrl = webView.getUrl();`

Answer (score 1):

WebView component has very useful methods. For example you can do it like this.

When your particular web page is loaded call `WebView.clearHistory()` and then, when you check if back pressed related method should be used, call `WebView.canGoBack()`.

Considering your example code it would be:

```
if(webview.canGoBack())
  {
    myfunc()
     {

     }
   }
   else
  {
     myanotherfunc()
      {

      }
  }
```

If you are also looking for the place where you could call above code, it's `Activity.onBackPressed()`. You can override this method. Please note that calling `super.onBackPressed()` will finish your Activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can Override `onkeydown` method

```
if (keyCode == keyevent.KeyCode_Back)
  // Toast.make
else
  // load your web
```